# Request user posts in django

Tags: django, django-views

i am currently looking for how to request the posts by the authenticated user and also posts by the users they are following or users following them. So far i have been able to show posts by users following them but cant seem to get the autthenticated user's post to show

```
views.py 

    events = post.objects.filter()
    following = request.user.following_set.all().values_list('to_user',
            flat=True)
    events = events.filter(user__in=following)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cannot see your model definition, but you need to do this:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
   events = request.user.user_posts.filter() # authenticated user posts
else:
   events = post.objects.filter() # all posts
```

`user_posts` is the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) from Django's User Model to Post Model. something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_posts")
   # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way unless in your view do something like

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    events ...
else:
    events ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Importing LoginRequiredMixin to push the user to log in.
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

# Post Model Importing
from .models import Post

class Timeline(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
     template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Timeline, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```